# Automated SMS and Email

Tags: email, model-view-controller, text, sms

We have a built an online course booking system using MVC Entity framework and SQL Server. The system sends emails out using an SMTP service and SMS using another service from textanywhere.net.

Now we want to send out automatic emails and SMS the day before a course to remind applicants.

Previously we have sent out automated emails by writing a VB script that would connect to the database, run a query and send out emails. We would run this as a scheduled task that would preform daily.

Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps run a script from within the application itself?

Your views are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Folks i'm returning to this one again.

Does anybody see any problems in implementing the following?

[ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server Application: Best Way to Send Out Event-Driven E-mail Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452236/asp-net-mvc-sql-server-application-best-way-to-send-out-event-driven-e-mail-n)

Certainly looks straight forward.